# How to receive the output of a server when being prompted by a Scanner?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, ip, chat

I'm working with a multithreaded TCP/IP chat application.

It's pretty simple - clients send messages to the server. They can invoke a `send CLIENT_ID MESSAGE` command in which the server will attempt to send the other clients who are connected a message from the other one.

However, because each client is being prompted by `"Enter a command: "` in the loop that is running, the next output they will receive is not the command they input, but the message from the server saying that their message was sent. And from the receiver's side, they will receive the message from the other client instead of the intended output of the command they entered.

So I'm wondering, how can I read the server's message while still prompting? Should I have separate threads for reading the server and writing to it from the client? If so, how can I accomplish that?

My client looks like this:

```
public class TCPClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try{
            final int SERVER_PORT = 8888; // this port needs to be the same as the server
            Socket socket=new Socket("127.0.0.1",SERVER_PORT); //localhost

            DataInputStream inStream=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); //reads a stream from you
            DataOutputStream outStream=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); // outputs a stream to send to server
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); // gets keyboard input
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(br); 
            String clientMessage="",serverMessage="";
            while(!clientMessage.equals("exit")){

                // read before and after in case of chat messages?
                if(inStream.available()< 2) { System.out.println(inStream.readUTF());} //my attempt at solving it...no dice
                System.out.println("Enter chat message :"); //prompt
                clientMessage=sc.nextLine(); 
                outStream.writeUTF(clientMessage); //this outstream is connected to the socket, so we just send it out
                outStream.flush(); //make sure there's no input left
                serverMessage=inStream.readUTF(); //get server message and print to console
                System.out.println(serverMessage);
            }
            outStream.close();
            outStream.close();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println("Chat is over.");


        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you will need separate threads, and you should do this as a GUI app, not a console app.

Comment: "Should I have separate threads for reading the server and writing to it from the client?" That is one common (and easy) approach, yes.

Comment: Ok, but in that case would I need to pass the socket to both of the threads? How can I do that? Do I have to override the run method?